Cmake 3.17.5 (Centos7): using ISO C90 whereas CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11
I have a simple program I compile with make via CMake.
The CMakeLists.txt contains
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

but I get lots of warnings and errors.

warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]
error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode

Why CMake/gcc4 uses C90 to compile my code?
Using CMAKE_C_STANDARD instead of CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD solves everything.

C++ and C are different programming languages. Variable CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD affects only on building C++ code. Variable CMAKE_C_STANDARD affects only on building C code.

Is there a check on file extension? Other than my file being .c, I don't understand why CMake doesn't use the C++ standard I told it.

Yes, CMake checks a file extension when choose compiler for compile that file. If you want to tell CMake to use C++ compiler for a file with .c extension, then you could set LANGUAGE property for that file.

BTW, C90 and C99 are solely C standards. When you see warnings about these standards, then you can be sure that exactly C compiler is used, not a C++ one.

I see, thank you!
